# Can the state stores in Kafka be shared across streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have a scenario where a statestore having some values from one kstream needs to be accessed in another kstream, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the same state store to multiple processors if you use the Processor API, but also if you use the [Processor API Integration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#applying-processors-and-transformers-processor-api-integration) in the DSL.

There are two ways to do that (see [javadocs](https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier,java.lang.String...))). You can either manually add the store to the processors, like:

```
// create store
 StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String,String>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
         Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("myProcessorState"),
                 Serdes.String(),
                 Serdes.String());
 // add store
 builder.addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder);

 KStream outputStream = inputStream.processor(new ProcessorSupplier() {
     public Processor get() {
         return new MyProcessor();
     }
 }, "myProcessorState");
```

or you can implement `stores()` on the passed in `ProcessorSupplier`:

```
 class MyProcessorSupplier implements ProcessorSupplier {
     // supply processor
     Processor get() {
         return new MyProcessor();
     }

     // provide store(s) that will be added and connected to the associated processor
     // the store name from the builder ("myProcessorState") is used to access the store later via the ProcessorContext
     Set<StoreBuilder> stores() {
         StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, String>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
                   Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("myProcessorState"),
                   Serdes.String(),
                   Serdes.String());
         return Collections.singleton(keyValueStoreBuilder);
     }
 }
```

These are examples for `KStream#process()`, but it works similarly for the family of `KStream#*transform*()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

They can be accessed with Interactive Queries.

Between applications or instances of the same application, you need to use RPC calls such as adding an HTTP or gRPC server.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html